# Comparing values of objects in array and making operation on them

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, merge

I'm trying to compare same field elements in objects and restructuring them. I tried to use `filter`, `sort` methods but couldn't achieve that. I have an array like this:

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    direction: "A",
    carry: 6,
    distance: 1.41,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    direction: "B",
    carry: 5,
    distance: 2.83,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    direction: "C",
    carry: 4,
    distance: 4.24,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    direction: "D",
    carry: 3,
    distance: 5.66,
  },
];
```

For example: Let's take `distance` field, they are `1.41`, `2.83`, `4.24`,  `5.66`. The biggest value (`5.66`) will be 100%, and other values can be calculated like [proportion](https://www.cuemath.com/proportion-formula/).

`5.66` -> 100%

`1.41` -> 25%

`2.83` -> 50%

`4.24` -> 75%

The `carry` field follows this way as well. The final result should be like that:

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    direction: "A",
    carry: 6,
    carry_rating: 100,
    distance: 1.41,
    distance_rating: 25,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    direction: "B",
    carry: 5,
    carry_rating: 84,
    distance: 2.83,
    distance_rating: 50,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    direction: "C",
    carry: 4,
    carry_rating: 67,
    distance: 4.24,
    distance_rating: 75,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    direction: "D",
    carry: 3,
    carry_rating: 50
    distance: 5.66,
    distance_rating: 100,
  },
];
```

I'm struggling for several days. Any support is much appreciated.

Comment: use reduce to find the maxes, and then map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way of doing this is to first find the maximum values for distance and carry. Can do this in 1 iteration using array `reduce`. After that use an array `map` to add the new fields.

```js
const data = [  {    id: 1,    direction: "A",    carry: 6,    distance: 1.41,  },  {    id: 2,    direction: "B",carry: 5,    distance: 2.83,},  {    id: 3,    direction: "C",    carry: 4,    distance: 4.24,  },  {    id: 4,    direction: "D",    carry: 3,    distance: 5.66,  },];

const {maxCarry,maxDistance} = data.reduce((acc,{carry,distance}) => {
  acc.maxCarry = carry < acc.maxCarry  ? acc.maxCarry : carry
  acc.maxDistance = distance < acc.maxDistance  ? acc.maxDistance : distance
  return acc
}, {maxCarry:0,maxDistance:0})

const res = data.map((e) => {
  const carry_rating = Math.ceil((e.carry/maxCarry)*100)
  const distance_rating = Math.ceil((e.distance/maxDistance)*100)
  return {carry_rating,distance_rating,...e}
}) 

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Thanks, is it available to place them in right order I showed in final result?

Comment: try rearranging in the final return statment. btw is the order in a object important since objects are primarily for key lookup. something like `const {id,direction,carry,distance} = e; return {id,direction,carry,carry_rating,distance,distance_rating}`

Comment: It's table data, so order is vital. I will try rearrange myself first.

Comment: I would be delightful if you could give a hint. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, doing it manual is easy. But I have many fields, I just reduced number of them to ask.

Comment: Any way to do it dynamically?

Comment: `carry
: 
"6"
distance
: 
"1.41"
narx
: 
"1"
obHavoQuruq
: 
"6"
tirbandlik
: 
"6"
yetkazibBeruvchiningMoliyaviyAhvoli
: 
"1"`

Comment: See? Thus, I was asking to do it dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

```
    const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    direction: "A",
    carry: 6,
    distance: 1.41,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    direction: "B",
    carry: 5,
    distance: 2.83,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    direction: "C",
    carry: 4,
    distance: 4.24,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    direction: "D",
    carry: 3,
    distance: 5.66,
  },
];

const maxDistance = Math.max(...data.map(obj => obj.distance))
console.log(maxDistance)

const results = data.map(obj => ({ ...obj, distance_rating:  Math.round((obj.distance / maxDistance) * 100)  }))
console.log(results)
```